# Conexion utilizando archivo .INI

Tags: ms-access, delphi

Tengo mi aplicación de delphi cuando la ejecuto en mi computadora funciona perfectamente pero cuando la ejecuto en otra computadora me aparece ese mensaje "Error en el disco o de red" el mensaje aparece cinco vences y luego se ejecuta 
pero las grillas aparcen completamente en blanco a menos que realice una acción(como buscar algún registro por nombre).
Este es mi codigo que utilizo para conectarme al archivo .INI

```
procedure TDataModule1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var BaseDeDatos, ConStr : String;
 IniFile: TIniFile;
begin
 IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'BDatos.ini');
 BasedeDatos := IniFile.ReadString('BD','Path','');
 If BasedeDatos = '' then ShowMessage('Error al cargar Base de Datos');
 ConStr := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
  'Data Source='+BaseDeDatos+';'+
 'Persist Security Info=False;'+
  'Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin';
 ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := ConStr;
  ADOConnection1.Open;
end;
```

Contenido del archivo .INI

```
[BD]
Path="D:\MICARPETA\PROYECTO\BASEDEDATOS.MDB"
[Logon]
Auto="No"
Login=""
Pass=""
```

Cadena de connectionstring

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data
>   Source=D:\MICARPETA\PROYECTO\BASEDEDATOS.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet
>   OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database
>   Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking
>   Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk
>   Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create
>   System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't
>   Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica
>   Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;

Comment: ¿Al ejecutar qué línea aparecen los errores? El disco _D_ es local? ¿La carpeta donde está el exe, es local? ¿cuál es?

Comment: @jachguate  Este mensaje aparece no aparece al momento de compilar si no cuando la aplicación esta ya instalada en otra computadora y la intento ejecutar, esta instalada en el disco C,

Comment: Me tiene pinta que tienes el componente de base de datos configurado con tus datos de desarrollo (tu maquina donde programas) y activado, por lo tanto al iniciar, antes de leer el .ini, ya se intenta conectar, en tu equipo funciona pero en el otro no.  Pon todos los componentes de acceso a datos como `active = false` (o `connected=false` no lo recuerdo bien) en el IDE y los activas por código (poniéndolos a `true`) tras leer el .ini.

Comment: claro, @pablo, entiendo que los errores aparecen al _ejecutar_ y no al compilar, por eso pregunto la ejecución de que línea es la que lanza el error. @Fly tiene mucha razón en que puede ser que hayas dejado el componente con la conexión establecida en tiempo de diseño (`Active` = `True`) y el error no esté pasando en tu código, sino cuando el módulo de datos se está _leyendo_ del ejecutable.

Answer (score 2):

Con un par de cambios simples es fácil que puedas solventar el problema, que seguramente tiene relación con lo que otros compañeros te han comentado. Es posible que el componente de conexión haya quedado activado en diseño y al crear el formulario intenta conectar automáticamente, antes de poder leer la conexión desde el fichero.

(1) Mueve tu código desde el `OnCreate` de formulario al evento `OnBeforeConnect` de la conexión (he añadido un `IF` al principio):

```
Var  
  ConStr : String;  
  IniFile: TIniFile;  
begin   
  // Este IF e pasa evitar circularidad, una vez la conexión se ha configurado  
  if BaseDeDatos <> '' then   
    Exit;  
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'BDatos.ini');  
  BasedeDatos := IniFile.ReadString('BD','Path','');  
  If BasedeDatos = '' then   
    ShowMessage('Error al cargar Base de Datos');  
  ConStr := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+  
            'Data Source='+BaseDeDatos+';'+  
            'Persist Security Info=False;'+   
            'Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin';  
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := ConStr;  
  ADOConnection1.Open;
```

(2) Define la variable `BaseDeDatos` en la parte privada de la clase, ya que nos servirá para evitar la circularidad.

```
  private
    BaseDeDatos:string;
```

Con este pequeño cambio obligas a cargar la configuración antes de conectar el componente `TADOConnection`.

Comment: El evento OnBeforeConnect te referís al evento del componente ADOConnection si es de  esa forma a la hora de compilar  me muestra el mensaje "Error al cargar Base de Datos" entrando en un bucle sin salida

Comment: Entiendo que te refiertes al Ejecutar no al Compilar. Por otro lado, el primer IF, justo evita que entre en un bucle. Revisa si has añadido esa línea.

Comment: El IF que tengo que añadir es el que esta comentado? con que variable lo tendría que comparar.

Comment: Sí, me refiero a las primeras líneas que hay en el código que yo he puesto y que no están en el tuyo. La primera vez que llegas a este evento, la variable  BaseDedatos está vacía, por lo tanto se ejecuta el código del evento. Al llegar a las últimas líneas (ADOConnection.Open) se vuelve a ejecutar el mismo evento, pero en este caso como BaseDeDatos ya tiene valor no se ejecuta, y no se produce bucle infinito. Para que esto funcione, la variable BaseDeDatos debes eliminarla del código del evento y definirla en la parte privada del formulario (tal y como te he comentado antes).

Comment: probé el código tal y aun  me aparece el mensaje de "erro al cargar base de datos"